# Pusher PHP "server" not working

Tags: php, javascript, pusher

first of all excuse me for my english because I'm not a native english speaker. I'll try my best.

The problem I'm having with Pusher is that I cannot trigger any events using [Pusher.php lib](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-php-server).

The pieces of code that matter are the following:

**JavaScript File:**

```
 $.post("pusherSend.php", { message:message }, function(data){});
```

**PHP File:**

```
<?php
require_once('lib/Pusher.php');

$message = $_POST['message'];
$channel = $_POST['chatChannel'];

$content = array(
"content"=>$message
);

$pusher = new Pusher('MY_KEY', 'MY_SECRET', 'MY_ID');
$pusher->trigger($channel, 'message', $content);
?>
```

Using my registered app key, secret and id.

I'm using the *Debug Console* provided by Pusher to try and see if anything happens but it's completely empty. I've already tried sending an event with the provided *Event Creator* and even displaying it in my app and it works like a charm. But I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong with the server part. I'm also using Firebug and Chromes developer console and everything looks fine.

Any ideas? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: Also, [this example](https://github.com/pusher/realtime-commenting) does not work for me adding my keys and renaming pusher_config.php

Comment: What's the value of $channel ? It is not clear if that variable has been assigned or not.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add this line up: $channel = $_POST['chatChannel'];

Comment: Yes, and I've also tried it with no variables at all. Just writing directly the name of the channel and the message.

Comment: You're only sending message-data through POST from your JS? Doesn't it work when you send "hardcoded" values?

Comment: Nope, it didn't work even with "hardcoded" values. I've edited my original post and I've added that it doesn't even work with provided examples like the one I listed above.

Comment: Ok. Have you tried something like $x = get_channel_info( $channel )  or $info = $pusher->get_channel_info($channel); ?

Comment: I'm not sure how should I try that...

Comment: I've made an answer, just so you could see an example how I would try first.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're having problem with the communication with the lib somehow. Try to see if you get any information about a certain channel:

```
<?php
$channel = ''; //Type name of channel here
$pusher = new Pusher('MY_KEY', 'MY_SECRET', 'MY_ID');
$channelInfo = $pusher->get_channel_info($channel); 
var_dump($channelInfo); //What's the result?
?>
```

You could of course do some logging to identify the problem:
Look for logging in the documentation: https://github.com/pusher/pusher-php-server

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I think I need some sleep, I'll try this tomorrow.

Comment: I've used logger as it follows:
Pusher.log = function(message) {
  if (window.console && window.console.log) window.console.log(message);
};

And nothing is showing up while triggering events. I've tried infinite ways, and still nothing happens. I'm starting to think it's not really my fault but Pushers. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem seemed to be the server I was running my app from. In localhost runs just fine. I don't really know why, because my server has all the requirements, but now it's working. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Debugging and logging should provide you with information about what may be going on. See: https://github.com/pusher/pusher-php-server#debugging

Comment: Well, I keep getting this when attemping to run my app from my web hosted server:

Pusher: exec_curl response: Array
(
    [body] => 
    [status] => 0
)

When running it from localhost returns a normal status of 200 and works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: That log line is come from [here](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-php-server/blob/master/lib/Pusher.php#L163). I'd suggest creating a very simple standalone curl example and trying running that. It'll probably highlight a problem with your web hosting provider - so it may be worth getting in touch with their support too.